# phpmyadmin fatal error execution on localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, execution

i'm getting this error while accessing **phpmyadmin** on **localhost**:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
            C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\streams.php on line 113
```

pls help! how do i fix it?

thank you!

Comment: Hi Aggeliki, welcome to SO. Without relevant information about what you did, did it work before, how did you install Xampp, and so on, its very difficult for someone to help. It's possible your server is overloaded.  Maybe you should extend the execution timeout... try to reinstall everything ...

Comment: Do you get this when trying to log in or are you able to see the main page before getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the max execution time by going to :

```
Xampp > php > php.ini(file) and 

search for - max_execution_time=30 and change it to 300.
```

And see if it works but what is it causing maximum execution time to take more than 30 seconds.